# Set fields using Reflection

Tags: go

I am struggling with some Go lang code for a few days.　I have a golang function that would set all the common fields like createdBy, updatedBy, etc inside a struct. I have googled a lot and have come up with the following code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
    "strings"
)
type User struct {
    UserId         string         `json:"userId"`
    ObjectType         string         `json:"objectType"`
    CreationDate       string         `json:"creationDate"`
    UpdationDate       string         `json:"updationDate"`
    Version            int            `json:"version"`         
}
func main() {
    //fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    var user = User{}
    var k = setCommonParam(&user )
    var p = k.(*User)
    fmt.Println(p.CreationDate)
    var l = *p
    fmt.Println(l.ObjectType)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(k))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(user))

}

func setCommonParam(obj interface{}) (interface{}) {
    entityValue := reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    entityType := entityValue.Type()

    for i:=0; i<entityValue.NumField(); i++ {
        typeField := entityType.Field(i)
        vField := entityValue.Field(i)

        if typeField.Name == "ObjectType" {
            vField.SetString(strings.ToLower(reflect.TypeOf(obj).Elem().Name()))
        } else if typeField.Name == "CreationDate" {    
            vField.SetString(time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))   
        } else if typeField.Name == "UpdationDate" {
            vField.SetString(time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
        } else if typeField.Name == "CreatedBy" {

        } else if typeField.Name == "UpdatedBy" {

        } else if typeField.Name == "Version" {

        }
    }
    return obj
}
```

Is there any way I can write the following in a single line?

```
var k = setCommonParam(&user )
var p = k.(*User)
var l = *p
```

and do something like this:

```
user = setCommonParam(user)
```

I am sorry but I am new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is "how to condense these 3 lines into one?", then the answer is:

```
var l = *(setCommonParam(&user).(*User))
```